# cheking on symmetric number

Tags: java, symmetric

How check number on symmetrics?

```
public static int Symmetric(int a) {
    if(new StringBuilder(Integer.toString(a)) ==
        new StringBuilder(Integer.toString(a)).reverse())
        return  a;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

I try do it smth like this but always return 0.

Comment: The idea is good, but the problem is the comparison. Using `==` you're comparing the instance values of the `StringBuilder`s, you should use `equals` to compare them.

Comment: Is this homework, by any chance?

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev looks like it, that's why I haven't posted an answer.

Comment: @GoranJovic `String` doesn't have a `reverse` function

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: Ah, to lazy to scroll, now I see, thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use `==` to compare `String`s (or `StringBuilder`s), you need to use `equals()`.
 Also, you need to turn the `StringBuilder`s back to `String`s before comparing:

**EDIT:**
Also, there is really no need for the first `StringBuilder`:

```
public static int symmetric(int a) {
    if (Integer.toString(a).equals(new StringBuilder(Integer.toString(a)).reverse().toString()))
        return a;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank for answer) But i again get 0 :(  System.out.println(isSymmetric(101)); return 0...

Comment: @RomanChyzh: This method yields `121` for `121` and `0` for `1231` when I test it.

Comment: emm... sorry) awherything is well)  i don't convert to string this : (Integer.toString(a))

Answer (score 0):

Equality is explained [here in JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21).

You must use [equals() on Strings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29): [StringBuilder.toString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#toString%28%29).[equals()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29).

```
public static int Symmetric( int a ) {
    return
       new StringBuilder(Integer.toString(a)).toString().equals(
             StringBuilder(Integer.toString(a)).reverse().toString())
       ? a : 0;
}
```